# Putting rounded buttons underneath the nav bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a navigation bar on my master page. Below is the code:

```
    <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #264653; position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); width:90%; height:14% ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <span class="navbar-brand" style="display:flex;">
      <img src="~/Images/Logo_Circle.png" alt="RCA" width="80" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
       <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e9c46a">My City Name</span><br />My Company Name</span>
    </span>
  </div>

</nav>
```

I want to put a rounded button right underneath the navigation bar without any space between the navbar and the rounded buttons. This is how my nav bar looks right now:

[image]

right underneath this bar, I want to put the rounded buttons. Below is something, I am trying to do :

[image]

Below is the code:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#" class="ui-btn-active nav-border" id=viewtherecent> Recent </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="nav-border" id=viewthefrequency> Frequent </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried to put these buttons underneath the navbar, but they're coming vertically rather than horizontally.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox to align our buttons vertically or horizontally according to your preference.

Do check the code below, I have made a navbar with the buttons like you wanted.

```css
*{
margin:0;
}
nav{
  background:blue;
 }
 
 ul{
 display:flex;
 }
 
 .buttons{
 display:flex;
 width:100%;
 }
 
 button{
 width:200px;
 border-radius:20px;
 }
 
 button:nth-of-type(1){
background:lightblue;
color:white;
}

button:hover{
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Page1</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="buttons">
  <button>Now</button>
  <button>Recent</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to change the background color of the rounded button to yellow. I did this, but it is not working:  button:hover{
     background-color:yellow;
 }
 am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The background for the buttons was said with the background property. Not the background colour so you should change yourcode to background. I have editted the snippet above. Do check it.

Answer (score 1):

Should you need to add `display: flex` to an element, do so with `.d-flex` or one of the responsive variants (e.g., `.d-sm-flex`).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <span class="navbar-brand" style="display:flex;">
      <img src="~/Images/Logo_Circle.png" alt="RCA" width="80" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
       <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e9c46a">My City Name</span><br />My Company Name</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</nav>

<div>
  <ul class="d-flex">
    <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active nav-border" id=viewtherecent>Recent </a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-border" id=viewthefrequency>Frequent</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<ul>` elements have a [default display value](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) of block, and `<li>` elements have a [default display value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-listitem) of "list-item" which ends up meaning block in this context. Elements with the `display: block` style rule will "[generate line breaks both before and after the element when in the normal flow.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#outside)"

You should give the `<ul>` element the following style and the `<li>` links will appear next to each other:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```